# Accessibility Service Double Tap Functionality like TalkBack

Tags: android

How to implement double tap functionality on Accessibility Service in android like talkback ? Is there any Api in Android ?

Comment: check this link it might help you in implementing double tap functionality http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.4.4_r1/com/android/server/accessibility/TouchExplorer.java?av=f

Comment: thanks , this link is useful for me

Comment: 's good to hear...it was useful for you.. Cheers .. happy coding